# Is it possible to send my external IP address to my twitter via direct message?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm currently learning python so if anyone could teach me how to do it rather than just putting the code to it would be wonderful. I'm using python 3.x

Comment: I'll see if google has the answer, but i'm sure someone on here might be able to add more detail if i find anything

Answer (score -1):

Try doing some Google Searches and look in the docs.python.org. They have a lot of tutorials and stuff. Good luck on your question. Also, this is not really the place to ask this type of questions.

Comment: I'm sure most people would consider this a comment, rather an answer.

Comment: and what would that do with the information in the answer?